# Is there a way to source a tcsh script from a bash interactive shell?

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh

I cannot rewrite the tcsh scripts to bash as there are many I want to source. 
(I found similar questions here, but not an answer that works. Like, tcsh -c 'source cmd')

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can absolutely run tcsh scripts from non-(t)csh shell but if you are asking if there is a way to get tcsh functions/aliases/etc. to work in a non-(t)csh shell then the answer is almost certainly not (unless the tcsh scripts are written in a portable manner).

Comment: I would remove the "almost" from Etan's comment: tcsh is a different language from bash. You would not expect to be able to import Python or C# code into bash: tcsh is just as foreign as those.

Comment: okay! So, the answer seems to be no. I would like to use bash, but the configurations of the product I develop is written in tcsh. It seems like i don't have a way around than switching to tcsh.